# Uninstalling an application from Jenkins

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins

I am trying to execute a batch file from Jenkins. I am getting some errors. My batch file calls a shell file that has code to uninstall the application

Windows Power Shell script code:

```
$uninstallString = gci "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | foreach { gp $_.PSPath } | ? { $_ -match "program name" } | select BundleCachePath
if ($uninstallString -ne $null){Start-Process $uninstallString.BundleCachePath -ArgumentList "-Uninstall -Quiet -Wait"}else{Write-Host "Uninstall string not found!"}
```

Batch File consists of:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -noexit -file G:\Uninstall\uninstall.ps1
```

Well, if I manually run the batch file, the application gets uninstalled successfully.

In Jenkins I am seeing the below errors:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Uninstall_pro
[Uninstall_ORD] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins7854020138412075044.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Uninstall_pro>"?G:\Uninstall\uninstall.bat"
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Uninstall_ORD>exit 3 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Are you using Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: No, free Style Project

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Jenkins [PowerShell Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin), this way you can remove the batch file and only deal with Powershell.

You can either use the PS code within the Powershell Step (removing the need for a separate batch file & Powershell script entirely):

[image: inline ps code]

Or you can remove just the batchfile - run the Powershell script from the step by using the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-) (this is useful if the script is coming from a SCM checkout):

[image: call operator]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried `& "G:\Uninstall\uninstall.ps1"`. I can see the SUCCESS message in the console output -

` Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Uninstall_ORD
[Uninstall_ORD] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins409083074826165197.ps1'"'.

' Uninstall string found! Start-Process C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{34daef0f-8bb3-4eda-8e93-96eb038bf1d4}\Setup_programname_10.06.00.038.exe -ArgumentList -Uninstall -Quiet -Wait
Finished: SUCCESS', but the application remains as it is in the Control Panel.